# How can I pass a fully qualified azure resource id through as raw json using conditional logic?

Tags: json, azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I am trying to conditionally pass through the fully qualified resource id of network security groups and route tables to subnets within a vnet. These are currently deployed using arm property iteration on a virtual network resource.

I have followed this article to get to this point. https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/29115

I am successfully able to attach route tables and nsgs to subnets based on populated property values. However, I am unable to construct a fully qualified resource id using variables and parameters to conditionally deploy objects.

I have tried using Azure ARM functions such as subscription() and resource(). However, whenever I concatenate my FQDN string using these functions I receive an error about malformed JSON. As per the article above, MSFT support are stating that this needs to be passed through fully qualified and I havent been able to come up with a way to do this and convert it through using the json() function. I tested passing through a short name of the resource Id and the ARM API also reports that I need to pass this through as a fully qualified name

I really dont want these hard coded in the top of my template as I dont know what the resource id is until these objects are created. Plus it is obviously also bad practice, defeating the purpose of a reusable template.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "location": {
      "type": "string",
      "allowedValues": ["australiaeast", "australiasoutheast"],
      "defaultValue": "australiasoutheast",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Deployment location"
      }
    },
    "routeTables": {
      "type": "array",
      "defaultValue": [
        "TrustedSubnets",
        "UntrustedSubnets"
      ],
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Array of interconnect route table names, (e.g. GatewaySubnet / Internal / Onprem)"
      }
    },
    "subnets": {
      "type": "array",
      "defaultValue": [
        {
          "Name": "Management",
          "Address": "10.118.124.0/24",
          "Nsg": "/sub/1234/resourceGroups/azresgroup/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/ManagementSn-ase-nsg",
          "routeTable": "/sub/1234/resourceGroups/azresgroup/providers/Microsoft.Network/routeTables/TrustedSubnets-ase-rt"
        },
        {
          "Name": "Trusted",
          "Address": "10.118.125.0/24",
          "Nsg": "/sub/1234/resourceGroups/azresgroup/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/TrustedSn-ase-nsg",
          "routeTable": "/sub/1234/resourceGroups/azresgroup/providers/Microsoft.Network/routeTables/TrustedSubnets-ase-rt"
        },
        {
          "Name": "Untrusted",
          "Address": "10.118.126.0/24",
          "Nsg": "/sub/1234/resourceGroups/azresgroup/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/UntrustedSn-ase-nsg",
          "routeTable": "/sub/1234/resourceGroups/azresgroup/providers/Microsoft.Network/routeTables/UntrustedSubnets-ase-rt"
        },
        {
          "Name": "GatewaySubnet",
          "Address": "10.118.127.0/24",
          "Nsg": "",
          "routeTable": ""
        }
      ],
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Subnet properties to be deployed per region. Each entry must contain a Name, Address, Nsg and routeTable key. Route tables and NSG's must be fully qualified"
      }
    },
    "vnetName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "hubvnet",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Virtual network name"
      }
    },
    "vnetAddressPrefix": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "10.118.124.0/22",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Address prefix"
      }
    }
  },
  "variables": {
    "alertsDistributionList": "dl_azurevnetalerts@email.com.au",
    "HubNetAgResourceId": "[resourceId('microsoft.insights/actionGroups', concat(parameters('vnetName'), '-ag'))]",
    "vnetResourceId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks', concat(parameters('vnetName')))]"
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups",
      "apiVersion": "2019-04-01",
      "name": "[if(contains(parameters('location'), 'australiasoutheast'), concat(parameters('subnets')[copyIndex()].Name, 'Sn', '-ase-nsg'), concat(parameters('subnets')[copyIndex()].Name, 'Sn', '-ae-nsg'))]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "copy": {
        "name": "NsgCopy",
        "count": 3,
        "mode": "Serial",
        "batchSize": 1
      },
      "properties": {
        "securityRules": []
      },
      "dependsOn": []
    },
    {
      "apiVersion": "2019-04-01",
      "name": "[if(contains(parameters('location'), 'australiasoutheast'), concat(parameters('routeTables')[copyIndex()], '-ase-rt'), concat(parameters('routeTables')[copyIndex()], '-ae-rt'))]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/routeTables",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "copy": {
        "name": "RtCopy",
        "count": "[length(parameters('routeTables'))]"
      },
      "properties": {
        "routes": [],
        "disableBgpRoutePropagation": true
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks",
      "name": "[parameters('vnetName')]",
      "apiVersion": "2019-04-01",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "properties": {
        "addressSpace": {
          "addressPrefixes": [
            "[parameters('vnetAddressPrefix')]"
          ]
        },
        "dhcpOptions": {
          "dnsServers": []
        },
        "virtualNetworkPeerings": [],
        "copy": [{
          "name": "subnets",
          "count": "[length(parameters('subnets'))]",
          "input": {
            "name": "[parameters('subnets')[copyIndex('subnets')].Name]",
            "properties": {
              "addressPrefix": "[parameters('subnets')[copyIndex('subnets')].Address]",
              "networkSecurityGroup": "[if(not(empty(parameters('subnets')[copyIndex('subnets')].Nsg)), json(concat('{\"id\": \"', parameters('subnets')[copyIndex('subnets')].Nsg, '\"}')), json('null'))]",
              "routeTable": "[if(not(empty(parameters('subnets')[copyIndex('subnets')].routeTable)), json(concat('{\"id\": \"', parameters('subnets')[copyIndex('subnets')].routeTable, '\"}')), json('null'))]" 
            }
          }
        }]
      },
      "dependsOn": [
        "NsgCopy",
        "RtCopy"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I would like to avoid hard coding resource ID;s in the properties of my parameter where I declare an array of subnets. I would like these to be generated using intelligent logic and then converted and passed through as raw json in the subnet loop at the bottom

I have obfuscated my sub Id at the top of the template. Please replace your values if you would like to test my template

Any help is greatly appreciated. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd probably do this:

```
"variables": {
    "copy": [
        {
            "name": "routeTables",
            "count": "[length(parameters('subnets'))]",
            "input": {
                "id": "[parameters('subnets')[copyIndex('routeTables')].routeTable]"
            }
        }
    ]
},

"properties": {
    ...
    "routeTable": "[if(not(empty(parameters('subnets')[copyIndex('subnets')].routeTable)), variables('routeTables')[copyIndex('subnets')], json('null'))]" 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help @4c74356b41 Your suggestion was most of the way there.. I just needed to build out the logic a little further which gave me the solution I was looking for. I posted with the working solution below :)

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "location": {
      "type": "string",
      "allowedValues": ["australiaeast", "australiasoutheast"],
      "defaultValue": "australiasoutheast",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Deployment location"
      }
    },
    "routeTables": {
      "type": "array",
      "defaultValue": [
        "TrustedSubnets",
        "UntrustedSubnets"
      ],
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Array of interconnect route table names, (legal values are -  TrustedSubnets or UntrustedSubnets )"
      }
    },
    "subnets": {
      "type": "array",
      "defaultValue": [
        {
          "Name": "Management",
          "Address": "192.168.1.0/24",
          "Nsg": "Yes",
          "routeTable": "TrustedSubnets"
        },
        {
          "Name": "Trusted",
          "Address": "192.168.2.0/24",
          "Nsg": "Yes",
          "routeTable": "TrustedSubnets"
        },
        {
          "Name": "Untrusted",
          "Address": "192.168.3.0/24",
          "Nsg": "Yes",
          "routeTable": "UntrustedSubnets"
        },
        {
          "Name": "GatewaySubnet",
          "Address": "192.168.4.0/24",
          "Nsg": "",
          "routeTable": ""
        }
      ],
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Subnet properties to be deployed per region. Each entry must contain a Name, Address, Nsg and routeTable key. Route tables and NSG's must be fully qualified"
      }
    },
    "vnetName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "hubvnet",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Virtual network name"
      }
    },
    "vnetAddressPrefix": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "192.168.1.0/22",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Address prefix"
      }
    }
  },
  "variables": {
    "alertsDistributionList": "dl_azurevnetalerts@email.com.au",
    "HubNetAgResourceId": "[resourceId('microsoft.insights/actionGroups', concat(parameters('vnetName'), '-ag'))]",
    "vnetResourceId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks', concat(parameters('vnetName')))]",
    "copy": [
      {
          "name": "Nsgs",
          "count": "[length(parameters('subnets'))]",
          "input": {
              "id": "[if(contains(parameters('location'), 'australiasoutheast'), resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups', concat(parameters('subnets')[copyIndex('Nsgs')].Name, 'Sn', '-ase-nsg')), resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups', concat(parameters('subnets')[copyIndex('Nsgs')].Name, 'Sn', '-ae-nsg')))]"
          }
      },
      {
          "name": "routeTables",
          "count": "[length(parameters('subnets'))]",
          "input": {
              "id": "[if(contains(parameters('location'), 'australiasoutheast'), resourceId('Microsoft.Network/routeTables', concat(parameters('subnets')[copyIndex('routeTables')].routeTable, '-ase-rt')), resourceId('Microsoft.Network/routeTables', concat(parameters('subnets')[copyIndex('routeTables')].routeTable, '-ae-rt')))]"
          }
      }
  ]
},
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups",
      "apiVersion": "2019-04-01",
      "name": "[if(contains(parameters('location'), 'australiasoutheast'), concat(parameters('subnets')[copyIndex()].Name, 'Sn', '-ase-nsg'), concat(parameters('subnets')[copyIndex()].Name, 'Sn', '-ae-nsg'))]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "copy": {
        "name": "NsgCopy",
        "count": 3,
        "mode": "Serial",
        "batchSize": 1
      },
      "properties": {
        "securityRules": []
      },
      "dependsOn": []
    },
    {
      "apiVersion": "2019-04-01",
      "name": "[if(contains(parameters('location'), 'australiasoutheast'), concat(parameters('routeTables')[copyIndex()], '-ase-rt'), concat(parameters('routeTables')[copyIndex()], '-ae-rt'))]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/routeTables",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "copy": {
        "name": "RtCopy",
        "count": "[length(parameters('routeTables'))]"
      },
      "properties": {
        "routes": [],
        "disableBgpRoutePropagation": true
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks",
      "name": "[parameters('vnetName')]",
      "apiVersion": "2019-04-01",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "properties": {
        "addressSpace": {
          "addressPrefixes": [
            "[parameters('vnetAddressPrefix')]"
          ]
        },
        "dhcpOptions": {
          "dnsServers": []
        },
        "virtualNetworkPeerings": [],
        "copy": [{
          "name": "subnets",
          "count": "[length(parameters('subnets'))]",
          "input": {
            "name": "[parameters('subnets')[copyIndex('subnets')].Name]",
            "properties": {
              "addressPrefix": "[parameters('subnets')[copyIndex('subnets')].Address]",
              "networkSecurityGroup": "[if(not(empty(parameters('subnets')[copyIndex('subnets')].Nsg)), variables('Nsgs')[copyIndex('subnets')], json('null'))]",
              "routeTable": "[if(not(empty(parameters('subnets')[copyIndex('subnets')].routeTable)), variables('routeTables')[copyIndex('subnets')], json('null'))]" 
            }
          }
        }]
      },
      "dependsOn": [
        "NsgCopy",
        "RtCopy"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```